# Powershell: create multiple .txt from one .txt with filenames from string

Tags: powershell

I have no programming skills, yet a very specific task: I have to split one massive text-file into many, splitting them at a specific textmark (@).
I decided to try Powershell script to accomplish this.

So far, that's what I have come up with:

```
InputFile = "c:\test.txt"
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
$a = 1
While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    If ($Line -match "@") {
        $OutputFile = "c:\splittedfile$a.txt"
        $a++
    }    
    Add-Content $OutputFile $Line
}
```

Now, what I want to achieve is not to simply base filenames on a loop. Instead, the second line of each new file is to act as filename, and I have no idea how to do this.

Edit @Jason Boyd: Specifying the structure of the file based on Jason's comment:
It is basically a large template for a wiki, which is why the resulting textfiles need to have specific names (in the first example "buenos aires_audiencia_rpl". The number of lines is not constant, since "Comentario" may be pre-filled and have line breaks.

```
@
buenos aires_audiencia_rpl
======= Buenos Aires, Audiencia (RPL) ======= 
^Variantes | | 
===== Comentario =====

 ====  Geografía ====  
 ==== Historia institucional ==== 
 ====  Población y economía ==== 
 ==== Iglesia ==== 
 ====  Bibliografia ==== 
 ====  Citas textuales ==== 
 @
caracas_audiencia_ven
```

Comment: Can you describe your text a little more?  Or maybe include a small sample of the file in your question.  Is there one `@` per line.  I am not sure what you mean when you say the second line is to act as the filename.  Do you mean the text after the `@` is supposed to be the name of the file?  If that is the case when does the file name end and the text for the next file begin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could read another line once your condition matches:

```
While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    If ($Line -match "@") {
        $OutputFile = $Reader.ReadLine()
        Add-Content $OutputFile $Line
        $Line = $OutputFile
        $a++
    }    
    Add-Content $OutputFile $Line
}
```

Comment: @Wernazuma edit this info your question, then @ mention Jason in a comment on your question instead of a comment on this answer. That will ensue he gets notified.

Comment: Wohoo,it's solved. And I even had to think myself from your input, which is great, since it means I got at least SOME, even if very awkward, understanding of how this works. Below $Line = $ OutputFile, I just added $OutputFile = "c:\Textfile\$Line.txt". Now I only need to figure out how to delete the new first line, since I don't want the filenames to remain in line 1 of the new files.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should post this as a separate question: To delete the first lines I tried creating temp files and then use     `code`Add-Content $OutputFile $Line
get-content $OutputFile |
    select -Skip 1 |
    set-content "$temp-OutputFile"
move "$temp-OutputFile" $OutputFile -Force `code`
to get this done, but it deletes everything but the last line, not just the first one...